# How to use array in ash?

Tags: ash

For some reason, I can't use `bash` to build my script, the only way to do it is with `ash`, I have this sms auto responder script, each reply must be at max 160 chacters long, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
    reply="this is a reply message that contains so many words so I have to split it to some parts"
    array="${reply:0:5} ${reply:5:5} ${reply:10:5} ${reply:15:5} ${reply:20:5}"
    for i in $array
    do
    echo "send sms with the message: $i"
    done
```

but it ends up like this:

```
send sms with the message: this
send sms with the message: is
send sms with the message: a
send sms with the message: reply
send sms with the message: mess
send sms with the message: age
send sms with the message: t
```

What I want is something like this:

```
send sms with the message: this 
send sms with the message: is a 
send sms with the message: reply
send sms with the message: messa
send sms with the message: ge th
send sms with the message: at co
send sms with the message: ntain
```

So it splits by the number of characters instead of splitting by words, how can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your array is not actually an array, but read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting for more info on that.

`ash` does not natively support arrays, but you can circumvent that by using `set`:

```
reply="this is a reply message that contains so many words so I have to split it to some parts"
set -- "${reply:0:5}" "${reply:5:5}" "${reply:10:5}" "${reply:15:5}" "${reply:20:5}"
for i; do
        echo "send sms with the message: $i"
done
```

-

```
send sms with the message: this
send sms with the message: is a
send sms with the message: reply
send sms with the message:  mess
send sms with the message: age t
```

There are many alternative solutions to this, here's one of them using `fold` to do the splitting work for you with the added advantage that it can break on spaces to make the messages a bit more readable (see `man fold` for more info):

```
reply="this is a reply message that contains so many words so I have to split it to some parts"
echo "${reply}" | fold -w 10 -s | while IFS= read -r i; do
        echo "send sms with the message: $i"
done
```

-

```
send sms with the message: this is a
send sms with the message: reply
send sms with the message: message
send sms with the message: that
send sms with the message: contains
send sms with the message: so many
send sms with the message: words so
send sms with the message: I have to
send sms with the message: split it
send sms with the message: to some
send sms with the message: parts
```

Answer (score 0):

sh and ash, just as bash does, "support" arrays through strings. When you declare a variable as a string with quotes and leave space in-between you can loop through the items in the array with a for loop.

```
#! /bin/sh

export SOME_VAR="something in between with,a,comma as an example"
for i in $SOME_VAR; do echo "This is an element of the array: $i"; done
```

And here is the output:

```
This is an element of the array: something
This is an element of the array: in
This is an element of the array: between
This is an element of the array: with,a,comma
This is an element of the array: as
This is an element of the array: an
This is an element of the array: example
```

Comment: doesn't this cause globs like * to be expanded?